# How to make the scrollView automatically scrolls to the last added value/text

Tags: android, scrollview

i have a `layout` with `scrollView`, the `scrollView` area is to be populated frequently with some text.
what I want to do it, to make the `scrollView` scrolls automatically  the last added message/text.

I have checked `Android dev` and i am not sure whther or not `:scrollbarStyle` is the correct property. kindly help regarding this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
scrollView.post(new Runnable() {            
    @Override
    public void run() {
        scrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);              
    }
});
```

Comment: aww, where did you get this. it seems it would work even befor trying it :)

Comment: but is not there any aternative to do the same job from the xml file?

Comment: You will need something like this android:stackFromBottom="true"
                android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"